# CodeKit for Mac - Windows equivalent?

Tags: windows, frontend, codekit

I have been using [CodeKit](http://incident57.com/codekit/) for front-end developing on Mac. The most convenient features are:

- Project File Organization
- Easy compilation and minification for SCSS, LESS and CoffeeScript
- Project watching, auto compilation
- Browser Auto-reload and CSS-injection

These features are extremely useful and time-saving. Therefore I wonder if there is an equivalent software on Windows with the same features? Or, can I DIY something like this by combining all the existing tools?

Answer (score 7):

http://mixture.io

I've only used it for five minutes and it has already auto complied my LESS files and live reloaded in my browser.

It is still in beta, it offers a huge amount that I've only started reading about.

Comment: +1 Mixture it's super powerful and cross platform

Comment: Looks like development has stopped on Mixture :-(

Answer (score 6):

You can try http://alphapixels.com/prepros. It can compile less, sass, scss, coffee and much more with live browser refresh.

Comment: +1 to prepros, it us the most powerful and feature-full for now

Answer (score 4):

Koala is an alternative that is quite similar to codekit, not as good but close enough.

http://koala-app.com/